# My Form Stylings Doesn't Match - HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I've been working on my site w/c uses built html editor that I can use and I am trying to copy the styles of the form on this page: https://imsc.clickfunnels.com/auto-webinar-registration10074792

Here is my current work in JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/su5rr2nh/1/

However I am not sure why I can't get the exact styles including the height, width of the textboxes and select/dropdown element. As you can see the images doesn't go inside the textboxes and also my buttons doesnt look the same.

**Heres my codes:**

```
<div style="padding: 40px; background-color: rgba(243, 242, 242, 0.611765); border: 3px dashed rgba(0,0,0,0.7);">
   <h1 style="font-size: 32px; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">FREE BONUS!</h1>
   <h4 style="font-size: 18px; color: rgba(47, 47, 47, 0.6); text-align: center;">Reserve your seat TODAY for this free training, and we will send you our <span style="font-weight: bold;">Amazon's Secret Business Cheatsheet</span> that will get you up and running in NO TIME!</h4>
   <input id="name" style="border-radius: 5px !important; padding: 10px 90px; margin-top: 10px;" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name.." />
   <img src="http://beaminggeek.com/profitbuilder/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/name2.png"/>
   <input id="email" style="border-radius: 5px !important; padding: 10px 90px; margin: 10px;" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Your Email.."/>
   <img src="http://beaminggeek.com/profitbuilder/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/email2.png"/>
   <select style="border-radius: 5px !important; padding: 10px 90px; margin: 10px;">
      <option value="desired">Select Desired Date</option>
      <option value="yesterday">Watch Yesterday's Broadcast Now</option>
      <option value="feb8th">Wednesday, Feb 8th, 2017</option>
      <option value="feb8th">Wednesday, Feb 8th, 2017</option>
   </select>
   <button style="padding: 13px 35px; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; color: #fff; font-weight: bold; display: inline-block; -ms-transform: all .2s ease-in-out; -webkit-transform: all .2s ease-in-out; transform: all .2s ease-in-out; text-align: center !important; text-decoration: none !important; background-color: #ea6645;">Register Your Spot Now! * seats are extremely limited *</button>

   <p>* we will not spam, rent or sell your information *</p>
   <p>Your Local Time: 4:18 PM</p>
</div>
```

I am tyring my best to copy every styles but its not going yet there. Any help to check what am I missing? Feel free to modify my jsfiddle if you want. I just want to copy the styles of it. I already use chromes inspector element but too many codes there.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE AND EXPLANATION**

```css
//text-align: left; sets the text start at the left of the input.
//border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2); sets a border with 1px solid design, in the color black, with an alpha value of 0.2
//box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); sets a shadow at the bottom of the input with 3px height and black color with an alpha value of 0.5
//background-color: #fff; sets the background of the input to white
//border-radius: 5px; rounds the corners of the input
//background-position: 96%; sets the background at 96% of the input. (allmost right)
//background-image: url(https://appassets1.clickfunnels.com/images/name2.png); sets the background to the image, that is found at the URL.
//background-repeat: no-repeat; sets the background to no repeat. Each background would repeat, until the end of the element. We only want the background once. so we dont to repeat it.
//appearance: none; some browsers let elements appear custom. we dont want it.
//padding: 12px 18px; to size up the input a bit. otherwise the text would hit top, left, bottom.
//font-size: 16px; sets the text size to 16px.
//width: calc(100% - 36px); calculates the with of the input. 100% for the whole area. -36px for the padding(18px) that we added to the right and left of the input.
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Name..." name="name"  data-type="extra" style="text-align: left; border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2); box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.05); background-color: #fff; border-radius: 5px; background-position: 96%; background-image: url(https://appassets1.clickfunnels.com/images/name2.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; appearance: none; padding: 12px 18px; font-size: 16px; width: calc(100% - 36px);">
```

Comment: Can you modify my JSFIDDLE I am confused with your codes.

Comment: Also where is the codes for the email, select/dropdown and the button? how can I integrate them on JSFIDDLE?

Comment: I'll give you a tip, i won't do your work. Right click the element, than check out the styles of it. It would be in the css of the site. Or you can directy find it in the inspector. Than you need to copy each css, which is applied to the element into your elements style tag `<input style="HERE">`. Or you just can add your own stylecheat (styles.css) and add the classes to your element `<input class="HERE">`. **BUT pay attention to the copyright of the site!!**

Comment: I don't think this helps. If you will read the text again above he already did that but he is confused with so many html and css.

Comment: @JimCarter updated, and at a whole explanation of the applied styles.

Comment: @JimCarter i did not add the other inputs. i hope you can do them. Otherwise just ask again in the comments :-)